# Do data types go into a Relational Data Model (RDM)?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I have recently been asked to draw a Relational Data Model for a flight information database. I came up with the design in the picture below, but I was told that the drawing is not correct because that is not quite what is meant by RDM and also because the data types are not included. Is this true? I have looked into many articles and books and I have not seen yet any RDM with data types in it.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Most people like the lines between tables to not cross. takes more work but even a large diagram can be a thing of beauty if you take the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:
Your diagram would be more complete if it showed the data types -- and a relational DB design must have data types specified -- but as a brief summary, it is OK to omit types for brevity, especially if your field names are descriptive enough.

Strictly speaking, the relational DB *model* includes the *table* and the *column* where a table is a tuple of columns and each column is of a particular *type*.

What you are drawing is a relational DB *schema* or *design* -- an application of the *model* for a particular business case.
Although, again, strictly speaking, what you have drawn is a hybrid between an *entity-relationship diagram* (ERD) and a relational schema -- even though it is a very common and *useful* style of diagram.

An ERD would not have any surrogate (system-generated) keys, as those are not part of the business semantics, but would have the lines -- labelled with `1` or `m` -- representing logical connections between entities.

On the other hand, a relational schema would not have any connecting lines as these links are not explicitly part of the relational model -- the links are *implied* by fields having the same data type -- but it would have surrogate keys.

As for the missing data types, yes, ideally both the DB schema and the ERD are much more complete if/when they also specify those, but that is not to say you cannot have diagrams of different levels of detail for economy of communication.